# Trying to add strings from a Form into an array on submit but I'm left with an array of empty strings instead. Using Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using functional components, I need to fill an array with string Form data onSubmit. `handleSubmit` is supposed to store the string data but when I use `console.log(value)` it returns an empty array.

I can't figure out how to access the user input from the Form so that it can be stored into an array. I thought that `setValue([value])` would be a method to accomplish this but clearly something is not right with my code.

`read2List` is supposed take the data from `value` and store it into an array when the submit button is clicked. I appreciate any ideas! Thank you for your time!

[image: console.log(value)]

```
function App () { 
     const [value, setValue] = useState("");
     const [entrylist, setEntry] = useState([]);
        
        const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            setValue([value])
            console.log(value) 
        }   
        const read2List = () => {
            const updatedList = [...entrylist];
            updatedList.push(value);
            setEntry(updatedList);
           console.log(updatedList);
        } 

     return (
        <div>
        <div> Insert Entry  </div> 

        <form class="entryForm"  onSubmit={handleSubmit}  >
            <label for="newEntryId"> 
            <span>New Entry:</span>
            <textarea  type="text" id="newEntryId" name="newEntryName" rows="30" cols="75" defaultValue = {"What's on your mind?"} 
        /> 
            </label>
            <button type="submit" onClick={read2List}>Submit</button>
       
        </form>
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below. I simplified your code. I removed `read2List` function, as you can do what you want with one function. I added comments in the code. Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-hill-5cospx) as well.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const textAreaRef = useRef();
  const [entrylist, setEntry] = useState([]);
  console.log(entrylist); // I added the console log here, to see changes

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updatedList = [...entrylist];
    updatedList.push(textAreaRef.current.value);
    textAreaRef.current.value = ""; // clear the input after submit
    setEntry(updatedList);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div> Insert Entry </div>
      <form className="entryForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="newEntryId">
          <span>New Entry:</span>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            id="newEntryId"
            name="newEntryName"
            rows="30"
            cols="75"
            defaultValue="What's on your mind?"
            ref={textAreaRef}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To know more about handling inputs in React, visit this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) from the official documentation.